# KDevelop crashes when importing cmake-based C++ project

Tags: kdevelop

I have a cmake-based C++ project (of about 25 source and header files) which compiles and runs without problems ("cd build && cmake ../src && make && sudo make install").  The project has a 'src' directory which holds the topmost CMakeLists.txt file.  When I run KDevelop, and choose "Open/Import Project", and then choose that CMakeLists.txt file, KDevelop starts importing the project, but crashes before the progress bar at the right bottom reaches 98%.  The KDevelop output is below; I can't make sense of it.  I should note that I can import that same project into 'Qt Creator' without problems.

Using KDevelop 5.5.0.2 on Fedora 31 with KDE/Plasma and gcc/g++ 9.2.1.

========================== KDevelop Output ==========================

```
kdevelop.plugins.definesandincludes: error while fetching includes for the compiler: "gcc" "Using built-in specs.\nCOLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc\nOFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none\nOFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1\nTarget: x86_64-redhat-linux\nConfigured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada,go,d,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux\nThread model: posix\ngcc version 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1) (GCC) \nCOLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c99' '-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'\n cc1obj -E -quiet -v - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -std=c99\ngcc: fatal error: cannot execute \xE2\x80\x98""cc1obj\xE2\x80\x99: execvp: Permission denied\ncompilation terminated.\n"

kdevelop.plugins.definesandincludes: error while fetching defines for the compiler: "gcc" "gcc: fatal error: cannot execute \xE2\x80\x98""cc1obj\xE2\x80\x99: execvp: Permission denied\ncompilation terminated.\n"

kdevelop.plugins.definesandincludes: error while fetching includes for the compiler: "gcc" "Using built-in specs.\nCOLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc\nOFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none\nOFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1\nTarget: x86_64-redhat-linux\nConfigured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada,go,d,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux\nThread model: posix\ngcc version 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1) (GCC) \nCOLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c99' '-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'\n cc1obj -E -quiet -v - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -std=c99\ngcc: fatal error: cannot execute \xE2\x80\x98""cc1obj\xE2\x80\x99: execvp: Permission denied\ncompilation terminated.\n"

kdevelop.plugins.definesandincludes: error while fetching defines for the compiler: "gcc" "gcc: fatal error: cannot execute \xE2\x80\x98""cc1obj\xE2\x80\x99: execvp: Permission denied\ncompilation terminated.\n"

kdevelop.plugins.definesandincludes: error while fetching includes for the compiler: "gcc" "Using built-in specs.\nCOLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc\nOFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none\nOFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1\nTarget: x86_64-redhat-linux\nConfigured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada,go,d,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux\nThread model: posix\ngcc version 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1) (GCC) \nCOLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c99' '-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'\n cc1obj -E -quiet -v - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -std=c99\ngcc: fatal error: cannot execute \xE2\x80\x98""cc1obj\xE2\x80\x99: execvp: Permission denied\ncompilation terminated.\n"

kdevelop.plugins.definesandincludes: error while fetching defines for the compiler: "gcc" "gcc: fatal error: cannot execute \xE2\x80\x98""cc1obj\xE2\x80\x99: execvp: Permission denied\ncompilation terminated.\n"

kdevelop.plugins.definesandincludes: error while fetching includes for the compiler: "gcc" "Using built-in specs.\nCOLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc\nOFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none\nOFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1\nTarget: x86_64-redhat-linux\nConfigured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada,go,d,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux\nThread model: posix\ngcc version 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1) (GCC) \nCOLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c99' '-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'\n cc1obj -E -quiet -v - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -std=c99\ngcc: fatal error: cannot execute \xE2\x80\x98""cc1obj\xE2\x80\x99: execvp: Permission denied\ncompilation terminated.\n"

kdevelop.plugins.definesandincludes: error while fetching defines for the compiler: "gcc" "gcc: fatal error: cannot execute \xE2\x80\x98""cc1obj\xE2\x80\x99: execvp: Permission denied\ncompilation terminated.\n"

kdevelop.plugins.definesandincludes: error while fetching includes for the compiler: "gcc" "Using built-in specs.\nCOLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc\nOFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none\nOFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1\nTarget: x86_64-redhat-linux\nConfigured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada,go,d,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux\nThread model: posix\ngcc version 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1) (GCC) \nCOLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c99' '-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'\n cc1obj -E -quiet -v - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -std=c99\ngcc: fatal error: cannot execute \xE2\x80\x98""cc1obj\xE2\x80\x99: execvp: Permission denied\ncompilation terminated.\n"

kdevelop.plugins.definesandincludes: error while fetching defines for the compiler: "gcc" "gcc: fatal error: cannot execute \xE2\x80\x98""cc1obj\xE2\x80\x99: execvp: Permission denied\ncompilation terminated.\n"

QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 6 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 10 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 60 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 75 and type 'Read', disabling...

KCrash: Application 'kdevelop' crashing...

QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 67 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 70 and type 'Exception', disabling...
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 72 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 23 and type 'Read', disabling...

sock_file=/run/user/2327/kdeinit5__0

QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 24 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 30 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 31 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 32 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 43 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 34 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 36 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 8 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 9 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 56 and type 'Read', disabling...
```